# How to stop protractor from downloading latest chromedriver?

Tags: node.js, protractor, webdriver, e2e-testing, webdriver-manager

I am running E2E tests using Protractor on Bamboo. I got this error unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Then I found that I had to downgrade to 2.37 version of Chromedriver. I found that here "https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4850"  .

I found a way to download a specific version of chromedriver here https://medium.com/@cnishina/webdriver-manager-a-node-module-c33a820f5eb . So I am using webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.37 .

On running npm run e2e as a pree2e step I do "webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.37" but after that once it starts "ng e2e" it downloads latest chromedriver (2.46). I can also see update-config.json is updated with both 2.46 and 2.37.

I am assuming if 2.46 is present then protractor tests will use 2.46 Chromedriver and not 2.37.

My question is how do I stop latest Chromedriver 2.46 from being downloaded? I only need 2.37 to solve the issue(DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) I have on Bamboo.

I am using "protractor": "^5.4.0" which installs "webdriver-manager": "^12.0.6" . Do I need to change protractor version?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add option `--webdriverUpdate=false` to disable webdriver update `ng e2e --webdriverUpdate=false`

This option has subtle differences in different Angular CLI versions. Check your Angualr CLI version, then get the precise option.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Alternatively you can also add this flag to the options of your `e2e` definition in your `angular.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays the parameter for not download is called:

```
ng e2e --webdriver-update=false
```